# There was an error ending this message to your bot

Tags: botframework

I created a bot with Bot Framework V3 and deployed to Azure. Everything works fine locally. Have tried out the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/troubleshoot-authentication-problems#enable-security-localhost and can successfully do each till step 4.

When I test in azure with "test in web chat", I am not able to send the message to my bot and I am getting above error.

How to resolve this error? What is missing here?

Comment: Can you post the error that shows up in developer console when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Would you please check this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90af15ce-16ce-49e1-980c-b3dba7b9e8a7/my-chatbots-suddenly-dont-work-on-facebook?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required

It worked for me